# rect collision with list of rects

Tags: python, list, pygame, rect

I have the code `player_rect.colliderect(tile_rects):` where `player_rect` is a single `Rect`, and `tile_rects` is a list of `Rect`s.
I get the error `builtins.TypeError:

> Argument must be rect style object

when I try to run my code (presumably as the code doesn't like having a list of rects over a single rect).

I also just found out than when I switch the positions of `tile_rects` and `player_rect`I instead get the error

> builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

My question is, how can I change my code so that I can check for collisions with a rect and a list of rects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to test whether a rectangle collides with one of a list of rectangles.

[`collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

> Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned.

```py
if player_rect.collidelist(tile_rects) >= 0:
    # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use a `for` loop:

```
for t in tile_rects:
    player_rect.colliderect(t)
```

if you want to check for any collision you may use:

```
has_colide = any(player_rect.colliderect(t) for t in tile_rects)
```